# using sed or awk to remove a "checkbox" character

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a script that has a variable that might contain some weird characters:  `✔`. I need to remove them but, honestly, I don't even know where to begin to match those characters. I can't copy and paste them into my script, they just show up as `?? ?`. How can a match those characters with sed or awk? I don't have the ability to use perl or php or anything much beyond sed or awk due to system availability.

Comment: Can you provide more detail?

Comment: This is a linux machine, a docker app actually. I have a program that sets environmental variables for custom post-processing scripts to use. I am trying to write a custom post processing script and one of those variables I need has those characters on the end. I don't know anything about character encoding or any of that, that's kind of my problem.

Comment: Well, you could try `file script` to get the encoding and maybe `hexdump -C script` to try and find the character from the script. Attach that info to your question.

Comment: Running `file script.sh` says it's ASCII. I ran `hexdump -C` on the output file and the character just shows as dots. Hope this helps as I have no idea what to do with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was just changing the encoding of the script to UTF-8 instead of ASCII. I did this with notepad++. Then I could work with the character directly instead of some roundabout way of converting to hex (which I couldn't do anyway as the variable is an environmental variable and not from a file) or something else. I also didn't need to use awk or sed as the following was much simpler:

`cleaned_var=${environmental_variable//"  ✔"}`

Answer (score 4):

First, put some flag strings around your special chars and then `hexdump -C` so you can easily see them. Then use HEX code to write the `sed` command. For example:

```
[STEP 118] # cat file
>>> ✔<<<
[STEP 119] # hexdump -C file
00000000  3e 3e 3e f0 9f 8d bf 20  e2 9c 94 3c 3c 3c 0a     |>>>.... ...<<<.|
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[STEP 120] # sed -e $'s/\xf0\x9f\x8d\xbf\x20\xe2\x9c\x94//g' file # need to use the $'...'
>>><<<
[STEP 121] #
```

Then remove the added flag strings when all is done.

Comment: Unfortunately the machine I am on does not have hexdump and I cannot add it. The variable I need is also an environmental variable and not in a file, although I could just write it to file. I'll see if I can get hexdump on there somehow.

Comment: you can also use `od` or `xxd`. e.g.: `echo 123 | od -t x1` or `echo 123 | xxd`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - (file contain some control M and the character that you have mentioned in the question and I am trying to print only the alphanumeric character)

```
$cat f


hello vipin
street1
pin 12345

 ✔
```

---

```
$awk '/[[:alnum:]]/ {print }' f
hello vipin
street1
pin 12345
```

Looks like control M character is getting disappeared after saving the input file on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
some weird characters:  ✔. I need to remove
second line of some weird characters:  ✔. I need to remove

$ tr -c -d '[:print:][:space:]' < file
some weird characters:  . I need to remove
second line of some weird characters:  . I need to remove
```